# Unequal spacing of columns in xymatrix

Tags: columns, xy-pic

Hello I have the following diagram in `\xymatrix`

```
  \xymatrix@R=2pt{A \ar[r]  &  B \ar[r] & C & D\\ E \ar[ur]  &  F \ar[r] &  & D}
```

Is there a way to reduce the gap between the C and D column to a custom size? I.e. set the width of one column to a given value.
[image: xypic]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Why not simply `C\,D` or any other spacing command?

Comment: I would like them as separate columns. It is actually part of a much bigger table and if I use C\,D the other table entries will not be aligned to the column anymore.

Comment: All columns are equally spaced. The usual trick is to reduce the column spacing and use two of them for a wide one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't have non equally spaced columns; but you can trick Xy-pic into thinking they are by straddling two columns when you want wide spacing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}

\begin{document}
\[
\xymatrix@C=1em{
  A \ar[rr] \ar[d] && B \ar[rr] \ar[d] && C\ar[dr] & D \ar[d] \\
  A' \ar[rr] && B' \ar[rr] && C' \ar[r] & D'
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]